# Merge docker images with common base

Tags: docker

I need to produce several docker images starting from a common base image, call it A. On top of A I have to add two layers for packages B and C, both coming in several versions (B1, B2, C1, C2 etc.). The two packages are independent, and I need to produce images with all the possible combinations of versions. I currently do this the naive way:

1. Starting from A, create an image for each version of B: A+B1, A+B2
2. Starting from A+B1, create an image for each version of C: A+B1+C1, A+B1+C2
3. Starting from A+B2, create an image for each version of C: A+B2+C1, A+B2+C2

The layers for B and C are created by compiling the packages from sources (this takes a long time), and in the above scheme C is compiled twice for each version (once on top of A+B1 and once on top of A+B2). But since C does not depend on B it is a waste of time to compile it for each version of B, so here's what I would like to do:

1. Starting from A, create an image for each single package version, e.g. A+B1, A+B2, A+C1, A+C2
2. Merge the images to create multi-package images, e.g. (A+B1) + (A+C1) = A+B1+C1

Each package is compiled just once and then each single-package image is combined with another to form the final image by stacking on top of the common base image (A) the two independent layers (e.g. B2 and C1).

Does docker allow to do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can in principle do this with a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).  This would combine this entire sequence in a single Dockerfile.  Somewhat abstractly, this could look like:

```
  FROM A AS B
  ARG B_VERSION
  WORKDIR /build
  RUN curl http://b.example.org/b-${B_VERSION}.tar.gz \
   && tar xzf b-${B_VERSION}.tar.gz \
   && mv b-${B_VERSION} b
  WORKDIR /build/b
  RUN ./configure --prefix=/opt/B ... && make install

  FROM A AS C
  ARG C_VERSION
  ... as above, installing into /opt/C ...

  FROM A
  COPY --from=B /opt/B /opt/B
  COPY --from=C /opt/C /opt/C
```

The trick here is that each `FROM` line starts a new image build, and so Docker image caching can start over again at each new `FROM` line.  There's no specific requirement that the build stages start from the same base image, though it helps if you consistently use only Alpine- or only Debian-based images throughout.

If you don't want to rely on Docker layer caching, you can split these up into separate Dockerfiles.  For both `FROM` and `COPY --from=...` you can use any image, even ones you built yourself.  However, Docker doesn't provide any sort of orchestration for building layered images like this.  You'll have to write your own shell script or Makefile that runs the sequence of `docker build` commands.

Comment: Thank you, I was reasoning along the same line of thought. The solution is still sub-optimal in terms of disk usage on the build machine, since the copied files will be present in two layers. But I guess it's the best that can be obtained.